# Comparing Checkbox Field to Current Date within Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I have my checkbox custom field (show_days) as values (1-7) to represent (Moo-Sun) and I tested it with an echo and it is returning the correct value. Example today is Tuesday and the echo is showing 2.

I am trying to compare it to the current date `strftime("%u", time());` to only show posts that have the current day check marked. Its not working and Im wondering if I need to add an `in_array` somewhere. Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
$days = get_field('show_days');
$date = strftime("%u", time());
if ($query->have_posts() && $days = $date )  { while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        echo '<div class="onAir"><h3>Currently On Air: ';
        the_title();
           echo $days. '</h3></div>';

  } wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty...after a lot of different comparisons and pulling out of my hair, I got it sorted it out. Comparing two custom field time ranges with the current time, and then comparing the selected day of the week with the current day and WP Query the posts and on top of that....my Wordpress timestamp was 6 hours ahead. Ugh! haha, This code did it

```
 <?php
      $time = current_time('H:i:s');
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
      $date = strftime("%A", time());
      $shows = get_field('station_shows', false, false);
      $query = new WP_Query ( array(
        'post_type'       => 'shows',
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,
        'post__in'        => $shows,
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
                  'key'       => 'start_time',
                  'value'     => $time,
                  'compare'   => '<=',
                  'type'      => 'TIME',
            ),
        array(
                  'value'     => $time,
                  'key'       => 'end_time',
                  'compare'   => '>=',
                  'type'      => 'TIME',
            ),
            'relation'  => 'AND',
        array(
                  'key'       => 'show_days',
                  'value'     => $date,
                  'compare'   => 'LIKE',

        )
            )));

      if ($query->have_posts() )  { while( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        echo '<div class="onAir"><h3>Currently <span>On Air</span> : ';
        the_title();

           echo '</h3></div>';
         }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the comparison ($days = $date) as a meta_query to the WP_Query arguments.

```
<?php
$datetime = date('Y-m-d');
$day_number = date('w', strtotime($datetime));
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'your_post_type',
    'meta_key'     => 'show_days',
    'meta_value'   => $day_number,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="onAir">
            <h3>Currently On Air: <?php the_title(); ?> <?php echo $day_number; ?></h3>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I had some different shows this weekend, that are only on the weekends, but it was still showing weekday shows. It seems like it should work. Im thinking that the show_days is not retrieving the selected values from the post?

Comment: To troubleshoot and compare the values you can do the following: remove the meta_key , meta_value and meta_compare arguments but add 'posts_per_page' => -1. Then in the in the while loop, echo $day_number and get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'show_days', true ). This way you can quickly identify any errors.

Comment: When I do that, the get_post_meta echo is showing "ARRAY"....I think that is where the issue might be?

Comment: If your custom field is saved as an array, the you can use print_r:
print_r( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'show_days', true ) ); But if you are doing a comparison to date('Y-m-d') then, obviously, your custom field should be saved in the exact same format ('Y-m-d') and not as an array

Comment: My custom field is a multiple checkbox, Moo-Sun and the values are 1-7....So I am trying to match the day of the week to the custom field value. I can't use dates for the custom field, because shows air based on the day of the week.

Comment: Ok, here is what the print shows `( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`....now this  is showing the right values, since the show right now is Mon-Fri (1-5). Now I just have to match the day. Today is Wednesday (3), and the $date_number will be 3?

Comment: Ok. Can you set ‘meta_compare’ to “LIKE” or “IN”? If this doesn’t work, I will show you how to build a “dynamic” meta_query.

Comment: Thank you! So I changed the compare to LIKE, and my test show for yesterday at 6pm worked like it didn't work before. However, at 7pm, the Thursday show was on the On Air...which it should not of been. So I feel like Im almost there..

Comment: ( sfdc_postmeta.meta_key = 'start_time' AND CAST(sfdc_postmeta.meta_value AS TIME) <= '07:53:31' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'end_time' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS TIME) >= '07:53:31' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt2.meta_key = 'show_days' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '{e08ae71c6f5b4e4eebd6a435d8db5a2ea12ed836ed556df5d73b617407280f03}4{e08ae71c6f5b4e4eebd6a435d8db5a2ea12ed836ed556df5d73b617407280f03}' )
) AND sfdc_posts.post_type = 'shows' AND ((sfdc_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY sfdc_posts.ID ORDER BY sfdc_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1"

Comment: Do you think changing the compare to 'REGEXP' will work. I just did a test and made my test show only for Friday 8am-9am and it showed up! Hopefully thats the answer.

Comment: What is the expression in your proposed solution? I think it has to do with the way you are comparing. Make sure both values are either number/integers or strings

Comment: So everything was looking good this weekend. It was showing correct shows on Sat, but on Sunday, it started showing weekday shows during the day...so it seems that there is a integer conflict or something.

Comment: Yes, make sure $day_number and your meta_key value are both integers.

Comment: Okay I changed it up and it seems to be working. only time will tell with different days, different shows. I changed the `$date = strftime("%A", time());` and I changed my select values to Monday - Sunday (full day names). then I did the 'LIKE' compare....lets see how that goes and thank you for your help!

Comment: I had a show to begin at 7pm last night (Monday), but all of a sudden the Tuesday show at that time showed. So my conclusion is that Wordpress converted to Tuesday at around 6pm Mountain Time (Denver)....I have the correct timezone in wp general settings.